# Laravel api returns value in postman but returns empty array in Vue js

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel, vue.js, postman

I have a small Api built in laravel that is supposed to return a response when an endpoint is hit.
The problem is, that same end point returns something in postman but returns empty data in Vue Js.
I have been battling this for 48 hours now, and is driving me insane, any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

```php
public function search_passport(Request $request){

        $pass = DB::table('passengers')->where('passport_number',$request->input('passport_number'))->get();

        if($pass->count() == 0){
            return response(['message' => 'Passport number not found, please fill the form']);
        }
        return new PassengerResource($pass);
    }// search_passenger
```

Above is the code from the controller in the Api

```php
Route::post('/searchpassport', [PassengerController::class, 'search_passport']);
```

And this is the route

```js
 this.$http.post('searchpassport', this.passport_number, {headers:{
        'Authorization' :  'Bearer ' + this.token.access_token,
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application'
        }})
         .then(res => {
             console.log(res)
         })
```

This is also the API call am making in the Vue Js

Comment: What is `$http`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this.$http` is Axios and `this.passport_number` is a string, you're missing the field / property name for the request payload, ie `"passport_number"`. Also, your `Content-type` header is incorrect.

Try this instead

```js
this.$http.post("/searchpassport", {
  passport_number: this.passport_number
}, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token.access_token}`
  }
})
```

You do not need to supply the `Accept` or `Content-type` headers. The defaults will be sufficient.

---

It's good practice to use your browser's developer tools for debugging. The *Network* tab in particular is great for checking the headers and data sent in your HTTP requests and the responses you get back.

Comment: Phil Thank you very much, is working now, i passed the payload as object as u suggested and removed the Accept and Content-Type headers.